# Alternative proof to, "every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic".

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

In Artin's "Algebra", he recommends proving this by "working with exponents, and use the description of the subgroups of (Z,+)." The recommended proof makes sense to me, but I have been unable to confirm if this alternative proof is also valid. Is it even possible to prove this fact without resorting to relative primality, Lagrange, or the first isomorphism theorem?

"Suppose a group (G,* ) is cyclic. Then there exists x in G such that (x)=G. Let H be a subset of G. Suppose that H is not cyclic. Then x is not a member of H, since otherwise (H,* )=(x)=(G,* ). So suppose that H is a proper subset of G.

Suppose that (G,* ) has other proper subgroups, and let F be a proper subset of G. That is, there exists y in G such that (y)=(F,* ). Since H is not cyclic, for all y in G such that (y)=(F,* ), H is not equal to F and y is not in H.

Suppose that (H,* ) is a group. For all x and y in G and with F a proper subset of G, either (x)=(G,* ) or (y)=(F,* ). If (H,* ) is a group then it is closed under the product. Closure implies that neither x or y are in H, since (H,* ) would cyclic in either case. So if (H,* ) is not cyclic, then it is not equal to G or a nonempty proper subset of G, so H is empty.

But if H is empty then (H,* ) is not a group, and so there is a contradiction with all of the suppositions. Therefore H must be cyclic."

Comment: I am having some trouble following. It looks like a proof by contradiction, so it seems that you would want to begin by supposing $H \subset G$ is a non-cyclic subgroup. I am not sure why you postpone the assumption that $H$ forms a group; after all, the proposition is about subgroups. Also, I am not sure about the assumption that $G$ has *other* proper subgroups. This seems potentially problematic since the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ has only one proper subgroup. You end by contradicting "all of the suppositions," which (again) confuses me. Suppose just *one* thing; contradict!

Comment: I guess the reason that I postponed the assumption that H was a non-cyclic subgroup was because it seemed difficult to argue from that point of view without first establishing that both the lack of and the existence of other generated subgroups of G contradicted the existence of H. I definitely recognize the issues with the order of the proof, but the only alternative I could see was supposing that H was a cyclic subgroup of G and then providing a long list of disjunctive possibilities that would all contradict the existence of H.

Comment: One last question: why would it be improper to suppose that G has other subgroups? I know that it's possible that a group has only a single subgroup, but wouldn't it also be possible to suppose that this weren't the case so as to show that H couldn't be such a subgroup? 
Thanks for your answers. The proof is confusing to me as well, but I also can't see a reason it could be wrong other than making the supposition that G had other subgroups distinct from H. So I wanted to check.

Comment: The goal is to prove *every subgroup is cyclic*. So, a sensible supposition to contradict would be, *there exists a subgroup that is not cyclic*. That way, if/when you arrive at a contradiction, you have shown the proposition at hand. Still, I cannot quite follow the reasoning in this proof, and I suspect "relative primality" is, indeed, a key ingredient (in some guise or another). Nothing in your proof seems (to me) to get at any feature of the integers, which feels problematic since every cyclic group is isomorphic to (the groups) $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Proving with euclidean division on the exponents of members of G and H is definitely a much easier way to prove it, and the reason I was curious in the first place is that it "felt" logical despite not utilizing any features of the integers. 

But I'm still not great at writing proofs, as evidenced by the lack of a good supposition, and so I have an unclear idea of how much validity to to attribute to that feeling. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: "Since H is not cyclic, for all y in G such that (y)=(F,* ), H is not equal to F and y is not in H." Why not?  There's no reason we can't have $F\subsetneq H $.

Comment: " Suppose that (G,* ) has other proper subgroups, and let F be a proper subset of G. That is, there exists y in G such that (y)=(F,* )." Why would F be cyclic?  Isn't that what you are trying to prove,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading this a few times, I think one of the major problems (not already mentioned in the comments) can be found here:

> Suppose that $(G, *)$ has other proper subgroups, and let $F$ be a proper subset of $G$. That is, there exists $y \in G$ such that $(y)=(F, *)$.

In this excerpt -- specifically, the second sentence -- you are saying that just because $F \subset G$ proper, you can write $(F, *)$ as a cyclic group generated by some $y \in G$. But this assumption -- that a proper subgroup must be cyclic -- is exactly what you are trying to prove.

In fact, a subset $F$ of $G$ (inheriting the group operation from $G$) need not form a subgroup at all. And if it does form a subgroup, then (again) you cannot assume it'll be cyclic or you are simply assuming that which you've set out to prove.

Comment: This was definitely what I was missing. Thanks